# Running a command after npm start in docker

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, graphql

I'm trying to create a graphql application that will have it's own doc page (using graphdoc package). In order for the library to work I need the server to run and then run the command "graphdoc" in the terminal.
I'm trying to automate this process so when I activate my docker compose it will run "graphdoc" right after the container is up (the container running npm start). Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: 1. generate docs from schema file. 2. use another container which will share a volume with app container. Its task would be to wait for endpoint to become available, generate docs in shared volume and then die. App container could then consume generated docs from shared volume. 3. try to create background process that would wait for endpoint to become available, generate docs in some directory and die.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.